# Accessing Tables and Data of the postgres database

Tags: asp.net, database, postgresql, psql

I have a postgres database in my app, app deployed and running on fly io. Database is working but there is something wrong as after listing my databases I get two databases one is beautifulpolish and the second one is beautifulpolish?sslmode=disable. I don't know what is this second one but probably here are my all tables and data. Below the link to my original post on fly io.
https://community.fly.io/t/accessing-tables-and-data-of-the-postgres-database/17328

Is there anyone who has any idea on why beautifulpolish?sslmode=disable would be created? Where there might be a problem in my code? I would be really grateful for any help

Please see my original post, everything is explained there

Comment: That will be a second connection to the same database but without SSL (encrption) over the connection. Presumably you can configure things to enable/disable either.

Comment: @Richard Huxton do you know maybe how to do this in asp.net?

Comment: Sorry, don't use it. Check the docs.